# Has MyEclipse implicit breakpoint in debugging mode in class URLClassPath

Tags: java, eclipse

I am beginner in `MyEclipse IDEA`. I using `8.6.1` version of it. My issue is: When I execute my program in debug mode, `MyEclipse` go to `sun.misc.URLClassPath` class and I must `Resume` breakpoint(by pressing `F8` key) and continue executing my program. `MyEclipse` stay in `URLClassPath` class in following thread stack:

```
1. URLClassPath$JarLoader.<init>(URL, URLStreamHandler, HashMap) line: 581  
2. URLClassPath$JarLoader.ensureOpen() line: 631    
3. URLClassPath$JarLoader.getJarFile(URL) line: 641 
4. URLClassPath$JarLoader.ensureOpen() line: 631
```

Note: this event happen when some `jar` file exist in my project `Build-Path` but when my application is simple this problem don't make and first breakpoint is my first breakpoint.

Why this event happened?

Comment: I've encountered the same issue. It seems the reason lies in the jar name. The original jar eclipse should open is 'gwt-servlet-2.1.0.jar' and during the stack frames it somehow became 'gwt-servlet.jar', thus unable to find.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I've reproduced the error and it is not possible to debug the application. The only way that I've found to fix this issue has been: go to "window->Preferences->Java->Debug" and disable the "suspend execution of uncaught exceptions"

Now is possible to debug the application and the debugger stops in the user breakpoints.

Comment: +2 If I am able to give. GREAT ! You saved me from this annoying behaviour, I used to KEEP clicking F8 :-(

Answer (score 1):

The only reason to break is when a breakpoint is hit. MyEclipse (or eclipse) doesn't add any breakpoints itself. I suggest you debug the application again and, when it breaks in sun.misc.URLClassPath, go to the Breakpoints tab in the debug perspective and inspect all the breakpoints you have set. If you double-click on each breakpoint, it should take you to the relevant source file. Hopefully, you can figure out how the breakpoint got there but to remove a breakpoint, right-click on the breakpoint and select Remove.

Also, note that, by default, eclipse will break on uncaught exceptions (though it doesn't look like that is your problem). This can be altered by going to the debug preferences, Window->Java->Debug.

Comment: Are you saying that the Breakpoint tab, in the Debug perspective, has no breakpoints in it? What is the line just above the stack trace? It has the reason for the suspension and will say something like "Thread [main] (Suspended (breakpoint at line 581 in Blah))".

Comment: Yes, in `breakpoint tab` don't exist any row. I wrote trace of debug in original question, but show following: `Thread [main] (Suspended (exception FileNotFoundException)) 
 URLClassPath$JarLoader.getJarFile(URL) line: 641 
 URLClassPath$JarLoader.access$600(URLClassPath$JarLoader, URL) line: 538 
 URLClassPath$JarLoader$1.run() line: 605 
 AccessController.doPrivileged(PrivilegedExceptionAction<T>) line: not available [native method] 
 URLClassPath$JarLoader.ensureOpen()`

Comment: So, it is breaking because of the exception (FileNotFoundException). This is the default behaviour for eclipse, as I mentioned at the end of my answer. I thought this wasn't your problem, at first, but now that you've shown the full debugger output, this is definitely what is causing your program to suspend at that point. I guess there is a jar file that can't be found but this should allow you to track it down.

Comment: your means is : there is a refgerence to a jar file but referenced jar file there isn't in classpath?

Comment: I assume that, because a FileNotFoundException is thrown in the method getJarFile. Try clicking the run button to get an exception stack trace on the console, which might give you more information. I can't really give any more help than this. The reason for the debugger stopping is clear - an unhandled exception is thrown - but I can't help you track the cause of the exception down. If you don't want the debugger to stop on unhandled exceptions, you can change the setting as indicated in my answer, but you will almost certainly have the application stop with an exception, in this case.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. I can't figure out which JAR it tries to load and fails. And there is no stack trace in the console. Interestingly, after I hit the run button the application starts and executes just fine.

Answer (score 0):

solution:
**in state of Debuging just search for window Breakpoints  > in prespective-debug 
and uncheck [Caught locations] options.**